# Importing a large SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've seen a lot of questions regarding this topic, but going through these didn't help so I'm asking..

I have a large sql file (around 50mb) which I cannot import using phpmyadmin as it's limited to 2.5mb.

I've tried to use bigdump and I'm getting an error that says that says that I'm using "extended inserts or very long procedure definitions".

I've also tried using the `source` command from the console, which also gives me an error message saying that the defined `max_allowed_packet` is too low, after changing it to 128M (was 16M before) I'm getting another issue where during the `source` command I'm losing the connection to the DB server (hosted locally):

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found to be working is to further increase the `max_allowed_packet` to 512M.

Then the following will work:

`mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < file.sql`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work from the console?

```
mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < file.sql
```

(Yes, there is no space between the `-p` and `password`)

Comment: ``ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 90: Lost connection to MySQL server during query``, Just want to mention that this is a fresh server install with the latest mysql version, if that helps.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,257281,257435#msg-257435 - see if that helps.  If not, I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Split and conquer or diagnose ?

Comment: @Ender: good point, I suppose I'd side with "split and conquer".  Now the problem changes to writing a script to split the DB inserts into separate files.  =)

Answer (score 1):

**In my case the problem ("Lost connection to MySQL Server during query") was in a corrupted dump file or in the misbehaving HDDs:**

First, I made a dump on the main server and then copied that dump to the replication server. But it seems the replication server had some problems with its HDDs and the dump became corrupted, i.e. MD5 of the original dump file on the main server was different from MD5 of the dump copy on the replication server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting or importing. If you are importing try CSV format.

You can export into CSV and then import. If it still does not import because it is large CSV, then you can break the CSV yourself to make it smaller CSV files.